# JVM memory erroneous statistics

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I have been looking in google for a solution to my problem but no success. 
I have a "near real-time" application that checks available memory from time to time and notifies the user in case there is no less than 10% free memory in the system.
I am using the following code to do so:

```
double free = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
double total = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
double freeMemoryProc = (free / total) * 100;
if (freeMemoryProc <= 10) {
   // Warn user...
}
```

This bit of code is working fine most of the time but is giving me erroneous messages when the GC did not kick in time to collect all unused memory.

**Questions:**

- Am I right when saying that `freeMemoryProc` is not a true measurement as it depends on when the GC kicks in?
- Is there a better way (preferably independent from GC) to calculate the amount of available memory for a my application?

---

Related question (did not help)

[Obtaining memory available to JVM at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021727/obtaining-memory-available-to-jvm-at-runtime)

Thanks in advance,
Regards.

Comment: If you need near real time performance, I would try to make your application generate next to no garbage e.g. using a profiler to identify where garbage is produces an eliminate it (not just reduce it) This is easier to do in some applications than others, but if its important enough you can reduce GCs to less than one per day.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for the comment. That is unfortunately not possible, my application is generating a lot of DTOs which are processed then discarded

Comment: so recycling them instead of discarding them is not an option for you? It sounds like they have a fairly simple life cycle.

Comment: You aren't working on S4, by any chance? Because I already submitted a pull request to fix the "shutdown if I don't think there's enough memory" bug. The answer to your question -- aside from restructuring the app -- is to run GC explicitly. Yes, it's "just a hint," but you'll find that it's a good enough hint that all of the Sun tools rely on it.

Comment: @kdgregory S4? What is that :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I right when saying that freeMemoryProc is not a true measurement as it depends on when the GC kicks in?

Yes ... sort of.  It is a measure of the amount of memory that is not currently allocated, not of memory that *could* be allocated if necessary.

> Is there a better way (preferably independent from GC) to calculate the amount of available memory for a my application?

There is no way to do this that is independent of the garbage collector.  In general, the only way that you can tell if memory that is currently allocated to objects is "in use" in the sense that it is not uncollected garbage is ... to run the garbage collector.

The best you can do is to capture the memory usage immediately after a garbage collector run, and hope that the pattern of memory usage is relatively smooth.

Note that running the GC simply to find out how much memory is left is a bad idea from a performance perspective ... and especially in a near real-time application.  (But I guess you already know that!)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. Yes I don't want to kick in the GC every second as that will kill my application' perfs.

Comment: You can also use the Memory and GarbageCollection MX beans in java.lang.management to keep statistics of memory usage. Then your should be able to track how much memory is being freed at GC, and send an alarm if used memory is getting high, GC runs and very little is freed.

Comment: "running the GC simply to find out how much memory is left is a bad idea" - true, but you can use a rough check from Runtime, then call GC if that check shows that not much is remaining.