# How to know occupied heap size during run time

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

I am trying to output the memory allocated to a java application during the run time of the application. I have access to the application source code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend you can use java.lang.Runtime class there are various method inside it which can help you. ya it is the possible duplicate of [Obtaining memory available to JVM at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021727/obtaining-memory-available-to-jvm-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to have access to that information inside your application it'll be enough to use jmap command. It's included in JDK distribution and you can execute:

```
jmap -heap <PID>
```

There is few more options (like showing live object histogram) so please refer to manual